# Creating an intersection and difference in ML New Jersey

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

Using the function `contains` constructed earlier, write a function `intersection` that takes two list (modeling sets) and returns a list that comes up with the intersection of two sets. So

```
intersection([1, 2, 3], [1, 3])
```

would return `[1, 3]`.

Using the function `contains` constructed earlier, write a function `difference` which takes two list and returns a list modeling the difference of the first set from the second set (Set A – Set B).

I've created this code `contains` which is down below, now my goal is to create both an `intersection` and `difference` function.

```
fun contains(x, []) = false
  | contains(x, y::rest) = 
    if x = y
    then true 
    else contains(x, rest);

fun intersection([], y) = []
  | intersection(x, y) = if x = y
   then [x,y]
   else [];;
```

Trying it:

```
- intersection([1, 2], [2, 3]);
val it = [] : int list list
```

Comment: You need to recurse, and you need to study the definition of set intersection.

Answer (score 1):

As for your `contains` function, it can be improved slightly:

```
fun contains(x, []) = false
  | contains(x, y::rest) = 
    x = y orelse contains(x, rest)
```

That is, `if P then true else Q` is the same as `P orelse Q`.

The higher-order standard-library solution is to write

```
fun contains (x, ys) = List.exists (fn y => x = y) ys
```

But the former is preferrable if the exercise is to demonstrate understanding of basic recursion.

As for your `intersection` function, it seems that however you managed to make `contains`, you are not applying the same principles of list recursion. You compare `x = y`, but here `x` and `y` are lists, not individual elements. Whereas in `contains`, `x` is a single value within a list/set, and `y` is the first element of the list/set `y::rest`.

So you should probably start to either annotate each argument with a type, or name it in such a way that you're not in doubt about what it's supposed to represent. For `intersection` the rule is that you only want elements that are members of both lists/sets.

For example:

```
fun intersection (xs, ys) = ...
```

Or with types annotated:

```
fun intersection (xs : ''a list, ys : ''a list) = ...
```

And you may think that you need to use recursion on lists by pattern matching on the empty/non-empty lists on either `xs` or `ys`. I've picked `xs` here because it happened to be the first argument, but this is arbitrary:

```
fun intersection ([],    ys) = ...
  | intersection (x::xs, ys) = ...
```

Or with types annotated:

```
fun intersection ([]    : ''a list, ys : ''a list) = ...
  | intersection (x::xs : ''a list, ys : ''a list) = ...
```

Then you can ask yourself:

1. What is the intersection between the empty list/set and `ys`?
2. Is `x` a part of the intersection of `x::xs` and `ys`?
3. What other elements might be part of this intersection (recursively)?